# Bouncing ball program

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a typical bouncing ball program.  I'm looking to improve and perhaps add to the program. For example, is it possible to be able to click on a ball and have it pause?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BouncingBalls extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    protected List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>(20);
    private Container container;
    private DrawCanvas canvas;
    private int canvasWidth;
    private int canvasHeight;
    public static final int UPDATE_RATE = 30;
    int x = random(480);
    int y = random(480);
    int speedX = random(30);
    int speedY = random(30);
    int radius = random(20);
    int red = random(255);
    int green = random(255);
    int blue = random(255);
    int count = 0;

    public static int random(int maxRange) {
        return (int) Math.round((Math.random() * maxRange));
    }

    public BouncingBalls(int width, int height) {

        canvasWidth = width;
        canvasHeight = height;

        container = new Container();

        canvas = new DrawCanvas();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.addMouseListener(this);

        start();

    }

    public void start() {

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                while (true) {

                    update();
                    repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000 / UPDATE_RATE);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

    public void update() {
        for (Ball ball : balls) {
            ball.move(container);
        }
    }

    class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            container.draw(g);
            for (Ball ball : balls) {
                ball.draw(g);
            }
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

            return (new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Bouncing Balls");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setContentPane(new BouncingBalls(500, 500));
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        count++;
        balls.add(new Ball());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public static class Ball {

        public int random(int maxRange) {
            return (int) Math.round(Math.random() * maxRange);
        }

        int x = random(480);
        int y = random(480);
        int speedX = random(30);
        int speedY = random(30);
        int radius = random(20);
        int red = random(255);
        int green = random(255);
        int blue = random(255);
        int i = 0;

        public void draw(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
            g.fillOval((int) (x - radius), (int) (y - radius),
                    (int) (2 * radius), (int) (2 * radius));

        }

        public void move(Container container) {

            x += speedX;
            y += speedY;

            if (x - radius < 0) {

                speedX = -speedX;
                x = radius;
            } else if (x + radius > 500) {

                speedX = -speedX;
                x = 500 - radius;
            }

            if (y - radius < 0) {

                speedY = -speedY;
                y = radius;
            } else if (y + radius > 500) {

                speedY = -speedY;
                y = 500 - radius;
            }
        }
    }



public static class Container {

        private static final int HEIGHT = 500;
        private static final int WIDTH = 500;
        private static final Color COLOR = Color.WHITE;

        public void draw(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(COLOR);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: “For example, is it possible to be able to click on a ball and have it pause?” This site is about reviewing and improving your code, but it's not here to write your code for you, so this part of the question is off topic.

Comment: @user2692751: What svick means to say is that your question is better suited for http://StackOverflow.com than here.

Answer (score 2):

when I was looking through your code I noticed that you have some Variables that you defined Globally

```
int x = random(480);
int y = random(480);
int speedX = random(30);
int speedY = random(30);
int radius = random(20);
int red = random(255);
int green = random(255);
int blue = random(255);
int count = 0;
```

and then you defined these variables again in `public static class Ball`

I am thinking that you wouldn't need to define these variables twice, but that you could define them once and use them throughout the code.  I am not entirely familiar with the way that Java works (syntax-wise) but I would imagine that you only need to define these Variables once and then use them throughout the code.

I know that the `Ball` class is created inside of the `BouncingBalls` class

**Additional**

to have the ball pause when it is clicked, just make the `speed = 0` {no movement} and then when it is unclicked resume the previous speed.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

1. You have a lot of magic numbers:

   ```
   int x = random(480);
   int y = random(480);
   int speedX = random(30);
   ```

   I'd suggest extracting these numbers to constants to explain what they are.
2. The `Ball` class seems unnecessarily tightly coupled to `Container`.  It also is coupled to `Graphics` in the `draw` method.  It feels like that is not a responsibility of `Ball`.
3. There are lots of instance variables at the top-level `BouncingBalls` class; many of them, such as `red` and `blue` are only used in Ball, so I'd suggest moving them there.

Answer (score 1):

I only looked at the code briefly, but it seems alright.

However, when you call `repaint()` in the secondary thread you started, you should probably run that UI repaint call on the UI thread.  See for example [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921009/swing-how-to-properly-update-the-ui#4921271).  Also, running a continuous `while`-loop might be overkill, you might just want to update the UI every few milliseconds (maybe aim for 60 fps).  You could do it by hand, or look at [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

And some minor points:

1. Instead of `MouseListener`, look into `MouseAdapter`. It's the same, but it avoids having to define empty methods. On the other hand, you would now have to make it a separate class (likely an inner class) from `BouncingBalls`.
2. For `random(maxRange)`, look instead at `java.util.Random.nextInt(Int)`.
3. In `move(container)`, the argument is unnecessary.  I guess it used to have some use, but you forgot to remove the argument after some changes.